# Getting hold of keys from TouchScreenKeyboard

Tags: c#, iphone, unity-game-engine, keyboard

How do I get access to single keys using TouchScreenKeyboard? I tried

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
     UIActions.DebugText("The A Key was pressed!!");
```

but it is not returning anything. There seems to be only a minimal number of methods available to this class. What's the correct way to do this?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FullKeyboardUserInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TouchScreenKeyboard mobileKeys;

    void Start()
    {
        mobileKeys = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default, false, false, false, true);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (mobileKeys != null && mobileKeys.done)
        {
            GameManager.CurrentDriftName = mobileKeys.text;
            UIActions.DebugText(GameManager.CurrentDriftName);
            UIActions.NumKeyboardView(GameManager.instance.NumKeyboardUserInputView);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            UIActions.DebugText("The A Key was pressed!!");
        }

        if (mobileKeys != null && mobileKeys.wasCanceled)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Touch keyboard is not meant as a way to input keystrokes, its a way to input text - you can always use an InputField